# How to sort an NSMutableArray of objects by a member of its class, that is an int or float

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have a class (from `NSObject`) that contains:

```
NSString name
int      position
float    speed
```

I then create an array (`NSMutableArray`) of objects from this class.  I would like to then sort the array by the 'speed' value, which is a `float`.

I initially has the `float` value as an `NSNumber` and the `int` as `NSInteger`, and I was successfully sorting with:

```
[myMutableArray sortUsingFunction:compareSelector context:@selector(position)];
```

where `myMutableArray` is my array of objects.

here is the function:

```
static int compareSelector(id p1, id p2, void *context) {
    SEL methodSelector = (SEL)context;
    id value1 = [p1 performSelector:methodSelector];
    id value2 = [p2 performSelector:methodSelector];
    return [value1 compare:value2];
}
```

Now that I am using `int` instead of `NSInteger`, the above code does not work.  Is there a more low-level command that I should be using to execute the sort?  Thank!

Comment: Sorting arrays is usually done using an NSSortDescriptor. This is the newest way of doing it and offers _a lot_ of flexibility. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to drawnonward, I'd suggest adding a comparison method to your class:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareSpeed:(id)otherObject
{
    if ([self speed] > [otherObject speed]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if ([self speed] < [otherObject speed]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

(You could collapse the `if`-`else if`-`else` using the ternary operator: `test ? trueValue : falseValue`, or if `speed` is an object with a `compare:` method (such as NSNumber), you could just `return [[self speed] compare:[otherObject speed]];`.)

You can then sort by

```
[myMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareSpeed:)];
```

As suggested by Georg in a comment, you can also achieve your goal using `NSSortDescriptor`; if you're targeting 10.6, you can also use blocks and [`sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-SW8).

Comment: Thanks Isaac!  I was able to get the above working in my code.  I cannot tell if there is much of a speed improvement over using NSInteger vs int, which is what prompted my initial question to begin with..., but this got me in the right direction.

Comment: My understanding from http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW16 is that `NSInteger` is really `int` or `long`, depending on the system (via `typedef`), so there should be no performance difference between `NSInteger` and `int`.  I tend to use `NSInteger` with Cocoa stuff so it reads like Cocoa to me, similar to how I used `NSComparisonResult`, `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedDescending`, and `NSOrderedSum` instead of the underlying C types/values.

Comment: Oh, and to clarify, while `NSInteger` is basically a fancy name for a simple C type, `NSNumber` inherits from `NSObject` so it's a full Cocoa object.  That's why I said with `NSNumber`, you could use its `compare:` method.  `NSNumber` can also be stored in `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc., while `NSInteger` cannot (since it's not an `NSObject`).

Answer (score 1):

```
int compareSpeed( id p1 , id p2 , void *unused ) {
  return p1->speed > p2->speed ? 1 : p1->speed < p2->speed : -1 : 0;
}
```

Although really you should make the above a method of your class like so:

```
-(int) compareSpeed:(id)inOtherObjectOfSameType {
  return self->speed > inOtherObjectOfSameType->speed ? 1 : self->speed < inOtherObjectOfSameType->speed : -1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: drawnonward, Thank you!  Your code looks like it should work, and I was hoping it would as it is more 'c'-like and less 'objective-c'-like, but when I integrate it into my class I get the compilation error: Request of member 'speed' is something not in a structure or union.  After rehashing syntax and trying various tricks unsuccessfully, I settled on Isaac's code.  I will revisit this problem and start from your suggestion on my next go-around.

Comment: You could expose speed as a property or method so you can access it with [yourItem speed] instead of yourItem->speed.