# Writing compare: method in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, nssortdescriptor

I saw this post: [How to sort an NSMutableArray of objects by a member of its class, that is an int or float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700797/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-of-objects-by-a-member-of-its-class-that-is-an-int)

And had something similar, but I wasn't sure how it all works and was hoping for some guidance.  I have an Array of Marker objects that have a Type ivar that takes on values of 0, 1, 2.   I want to have a check box that says what to order by, 0, 1, or 2.

I started off by trying to doing something similar in my own method:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)Type:(id)otherObject {
    if ([self Type] > [otherObject Type]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if ([self Type] < [otherObject Type]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

In my .h file:

```
NSInteger _type; 
@property NSInteger Type;
```

I get the two warnings: 
Ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('id' and NSInteger')
Method - Type not found (return type defaults to 'id')

I don't think I understand what is happening when you call the sort method.  Thanks.

Comment: It might be helpful to see your header file where Type is defined in order to see if the answer below is on the right track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if you're explicit about the input type being a `YourObjectType *` (or whatever your object is called) rather than `id`? To be completely safe you should check the type of the incoming object anyway (as it may not respond to 'Type' at all, or may return something else with the same selector), so you'd end up with:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)Type:(YourObjectType *)otherObject {
    if(![otherObject isKindOfClass:[YourObjectType class]]) return NSOrderedSame;

    if ([self Type] > [otherObject Type]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if ([self Type] < [otherObject Type]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

I'm basically making the same guess as highlycaffeinated, that the compiler is failing to correctly determine the return type of 'Type', but my guess is that it's because of an incorrect compiler prediction about the incoming object.

To explain the whole process:

When you ask NSArray to sortUsingSelector, it'll apply some sorting algorithm that requires it to be able to compare any two objects within it. When it needs to compare two objects, it'll send the selector you supplied, then use the result you return — so with Ascending/Descending you're specifying the order that the two objects would appear in if correctly sorted.

For example, if you had an NSArray filled with objects of type SillyObjectType and you issued a `sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)` then NSArray would apply some unspecified sorting algorithm that involved sending the selector `compare:` to instances of SillyObjectType. Each SillyObjectType is being asked "should you come before, after, or at an equal place to this other object?". It replies with NSOrderedAscending, Descending or Same.

This is one place where ObjC's dynamic dispatch gives a slightly different way of writing the thing than you'd use in e.g. C++. The selector will be sent to the objects in the array, so you should implement it on those objects. In each case the normal rules apply, so `self` will be that instance of that class.

Comment: So I looked at it some more and I think I am doing something wrong by not understand what is really going on. So in my class that is a popup controller, I did [self _type] and I get the same warnings, and no output when I try to NSLog it. However, if I create a Marker object, and I set the Type variable, and do self.Type, then I get an output when I NSLog it. Int he NSComparisonResult method above, self is the array of Marker objects I use to call this method right? Also could you explain the logic returning NSOrderedAscending vs NSOrderedDescending in the first part of the method? Thx.

Comment: My answer got a bit too long to fit on as a comment; I've amended my complete answer above.

Comment: Ok great, that makes sense.  I still have the problem of using [self Type].  The first warning is the same as before, the second is: Method '-Type' not found (return type defaults to 'id').  Is this because I'm in a ViewController class?  I would think that self is referring to the object that's calling it, in my case, an array of Markers, that has a property called Type, which I am trying to compare.  When I try running it, it crashes on the [self.Markers sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareType:)] call.  Any other thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: If you did sortUsingSelector:@selector(myCompare:) on an NSArray filled with objects of type ObjectType, you'd need to implement myCompare: on ObjectType, and self would refer to that instance of ObjectType.

Comment: Maybe that's where I am doing it incorrectly.  I have my compare: method in the class I am in (a view controller) instead of the object class itself.  I remember writing a compare: method in Java in the object class itself. Does the same concept apply here? If that is the case, does the selector know to use that method in my view controller class? Thx a bunch Tommy!

Comment: Yep, it should go into the class itself rather than the view controller. Selectors are essentially more limited strings — they're not tied to any particular object or method implementation. Every time you call a method on a class, ObjC does the equivalent of asking the class whether an implementation is supplied for that selector, calling the implementation if so, or doing some fallback stuff if not. You can actually shuffle which selectors are implemented and by which bits of code at runtime if you want. It's one of the big differences from most other compiled languages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've defined `Type` as an ivar and not a property, therefore it won't be visible in `otherObject`.  Expose it as a property and your comparison should work.

Comment: It is declared in my .h as a property.  Or is it declared incorrectly?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a corresponding @synthesize declaration in your .m?

Comment: Yes, @synthesize Type = _type;.