# Comparing an object within a class syntax help;

Tags: c++, objective-c, class, object

I'm more confident using C++ than objective c, i'm just having the stupid issue of trying to compare two objects(of the UniqueWord class I'm building). I keep recieving the error, 
Expect a type; This is a basic question, but i would also like an explanation on how i was doing this wrong, This is what i wrote in C++. Works just fine

```
private:

  vector <int> LineNumbers;
  string wordCatalog;// the current word in the line number
  int newIndex(const int);
public:

  UniqueWord(const string,const int);//creates the unique word object
  ~UniqueWord(void);

  void addLine(const int);
  static int compare(const UniqueWord&, const UniqueWord&);//my issue here
  string toString() const;
```

My problem is typing this in Objective C. This is what i typed in Objective_c

```
@interface UniqueWord : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray *LineNumbers;
@property NSString *wordCatalog;
UniqueWord *UWord(const NSString*, const int);//creates a unique word object
int newIndex(const int);

-(void) addLine:(const int)line;
-(static NSInteger) compare:(UniqueWord *self)a with:(UniqueWord *self)b;//my issue
-(NSString*) toString;

@end
```

I would really appreciate to explain basic syntax rules (explained in modern language)so i wont have this trouble next time, Thank you. Again i'm not very confident in Objective C

On a side note can someone tell me if i the uniqueWord constructor right? where it says //creates an unique word object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `static` methods in Objective-C - you need a class method for that. Replace `-` with `+` in front of the declaration, like this:

```
+(NSInteger) compare:(UniqueWord *self)a with:(UniqueWord *self)b;
```

Class methods are similar to C++ static member functions, but since method dispatching is implemented more dynamically in Objective-C, you can provide an override for them in your derived classes.

The above would compile. However, this would *not* be idiomatic to Objective-C, because Cocoa uses [`NSComparisonResult`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult) instead of `NSInteger` as the return type of comparison methods:

```
+(NSComparisonResult) compare:(UniqueWord *self)a with:(UniqueWord *self)b;
```

In addition, constructors of C++ are implemented through *designated initializers*: this

```
UniqueWord *UWord(const NSString*, const int);
```

should look like this:

```
-(id)initWithString:(NSString*)str andIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

and/or like this:

```
+(id)wordWithString:(NSString*)str andIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

Comment: can you explain the + sign for me instead of - please?

Comment: Maybe, but isn't a better answer to implement instance equality and hash?

Comment: and is there a replacement for static?

Comment: @OPJ In Objective-C minus `-` means "instance method" (non-static member function in C++), and plus `+` means "class method" (closely corresponds to static member function in C++, but not exactly it).

Comment: @OPJ `static` in C++ can be used in many contexts. In Objective-C you can have methods that behave almost like static methods of C++, but you cannot define static data members the way that you do it in C++. Instead, you define a class method, and make it return a `static` object from inside a function or from inside an implementation file.

Comment: Thank you guys! i really appreciate the feedback. I have one more question where i declare a Unique Word object in Objective C,(where it says //creates a UniqueWord Object) is that syntax correct, will i get the same output as i did on C++?

Answer (score 1):

I think better advice is to implement an instance `compare:` method.  [A good answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498019/writing-compare-method-in-objective-c).

There's good reason to do this, specifically, the very next thing you'll want to do with your new `compare:` method is sort an array of unique words.  The class method that @dasblinkenlight suggests (with impeccable syntax) will force you to write you're own sort.  An instance `compare:` provides compact and probably much more efficient alternative:

```
[myArrayFullOfUniqueWords sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```